# TypeError: this.props.update is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Iam trying to do two way binding in react.where if we change any value in parent or child, it should reflect in another component. Since it is getting error while passing the input value. please help.

parent

```
export default class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: "sample"
    };
  }
  updated(changeValue) {
    this.setState({
      value: changeValue
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.value} </h1>
        <App value={this.state.value} update={this.updated.bind(this)} />
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

child :

```
class App extends Component {
  update(event) {
    var changeValue = event.target.value;
    this.props.update(changeValue);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.update.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is quite strange to see `App` as a child

Comment: Your code is working fine, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/gkysmsqz/9/. Might be something in your setup?

Comment: you can do an event update in header(parent component) itself, and code is working fine as @Chase DeAnda says, check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ppfnv2